# Add Sound Control Panel to Startup

Tags: windows-7, audio

I recently received a Logitech G930, and if you have one you may be aware of the issues some people face with the drives on 64 bit windows. To keep a long story short, in order to get the headset to work properly, I need to bring up the Sound Control Panel every time I start up and play a few test sounds in the Sounds tab. If I attempt to play any game or youtube video it just locks up attempting to load until I play a test sound from the Sounds tab of the Sounds control panel. I am not asking how to fix this, but whether how to add the Sound Control panel to the msconfig startup list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not add a shortcut to `%windir%\System32\mmsys.cpl` to your Startup folder (`%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`)?

In any case, the file you're looking for is `%windir%\System32\mmsys.cpl`.